# Moving UIView in Auto Layout environment

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, autolayout

In my view controller I have two objects. TopView and CustomScrollView.
I would like to position TopView at top and CustomScrollView beneath them so I put this :

```
// TOP VIEW LAYOUT

// horizontal

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|    [_topView]|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_topView, self)]];
// vertical

 [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_topView(89)]" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_topView, self)]];


// CUSTOMSCROLLVIEW

// horizontal

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_customScrollVeiw]|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_customScrollVeiw, self)]];
// vertical

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_topView]-(0)-[_customScrollVeiw]|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_customScrollVeiw, _topView,  self)]];
```

and works fine.

But now I would like to move Top view as I scroll in CustomScrollView so I create this function :

```
- (void) moveOnScroll: (CGPoint) offset contentSize: (CGSize) contentSize
{
float delta = offset.y - self.yPosition;
if (self.yPosition > offset.y) {
    if (labs(self.frame.origin.y) < self.frame.size.height/50 ){
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    }

    else if (self.frame.origin.y - delta < 0 && offset.y < (contentSize.height - self.screenHeight)){
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.origin.y - delta, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    }
    else{
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    }
}
else {
    if (self.frame.origin.y > (- self.frame.size.height  + self.labelHeight) && offset.y > 0){

        if (self.frame.origin.y - delta < (- self.frame.size.height  + self.labelHeight )) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(0, (- self.frame.size.height  + self.labelHeight ), self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
        }
        else{
            self.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.origin.y - delta , self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
        }
    }
}
self.yPosition = offset.y;
}
```

Now TopView is hiding as I scroll but CustomScrollView is not hugging to the TopView any more, it stays at his position and don't move. (V:[_topView]-(0)-[_customScrollVeiw]|)

how to fix this?

Comment: Use this : https://github.com/iMartinKiss/KeepLayout it will make your life easier about AutoLayout

Comment: And about your question, once you use AutoLayout, you shouldn't touch to frames directly if you don't want to mess up everything

Comment: Yes I thought that this might be a problem. But how to change Y property without changing frame with auto layout.

Comment: You need to change the constraints. @AncAinu That KeepLayout library looks nice!

Comment: V:|[_topView(89)] this one ?

Comment: If you use KeepLayout, you can change your top constraint **with animation** like this :
`[self.view keepAnimateWithDuration:0.35 layout:^(void) {
myView.keepTopInset.equal = KeepRequired(0);
}];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save this constraint somewhere in your view controller

```
// vertical
NSArray *topViewContstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_topView(89)]" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_topView, self)]
for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in topViewContstraints) {
    if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeHeight) {
        _topViewConstraint = constraint;
        break;
    }
}
[self.view addConstraints:topViewContstraints];
```

then change y position of top view via saved constraint:

```
_topViewConstraint.constant = yOffset;
```

where yOffset it's calculated value in your custom method.

Oh, and you will want to animate this changes:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
         [_topView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_topView(89)]" is a Array of constraints. Can I change the constant of array ?

Comment: Check, if there's only one constraint in array or not, if one - get and edit it, if not, I will edit my answer=)

Comment: Yes there was two items. The first was hugging the top and second was specific height. The only mistake is that I have to put -yOffset :D Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MarkoZadravec I've changed answer. Now it choose constraint that you want to save. Good Luck!

Comment: @Ossis Thank you a lot, can you please look at another question of mine named UIScrollView tiled subview with Auto Layout cause I realy can't figure it out.